# Change the title of my action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title

I'm trying to change the title of the action bar when returning from another activity.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Log.d("TOOLBAR", getSupportActionBar().getTitle().toString());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title 2");
    Log.d("TOOLBAR 2", getSupportActionBar().getTitle().toString());
    }
```

where in the onCreate method:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

If for example my previous title was "title 1", I can read these logs:

```
TOOLBAR: title
TOOLBAR 2: title 2
```

but in the emulator the title isn't changed.
I tried also to change the title of toolbar.

**EDIT**: 
This is my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="cct.sss.ViewRecordActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_view_record" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/view_record_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:onClick="editRecord"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Any chance you are maybe resetting the title to the original value perhaps in onResume or somewhere else?

Comment: Can you post the xml layout file that you're using for your activity?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I've edited the question. And I'm no resetting the title to the original value, I don't use onResume().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. I solved my problem simply setting the title of the collapsing toolbar layout in onActivityResult():

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("title");
```

Comment: This is the only solution that allowed me updating title based on `LiveData`. Also works with data binding `<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout app:title="@{...}">`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the `Toolbar` title while returning to an activity , you may change it in `onResume()`:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title 2");
        Log.d("TOOLBAR 2", getSupportActionBar().getTitle().toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title 2");
```

With

```
setTitle("title 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

At the onActivityResult method.

It should not be necessary to have it here.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` in `onActivityResult` function. But you should call this in `onCreate`.

To change the title of action bar you can simply call `toolbar.setTitle("Title 2")` inside `onActivityResult` since you already have reference to `toolbar` in your activity.

Update code will look like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    toolbar.setTitle("Title 2");
}
```